# Python Pandas Parser Error when loading large csv file

Tags: python, pandas, large-data, chunks

I am learning about loading large csv files into python via pandas.  I am using anaconda and python 3 with a pc with 64 GB of RAM.

The Loan_Portfolio_Example_Large.csv dataset consists of 2509 columns and 100,000 rows and is approximately 1.4 GBs.

I can run the following code without error:

```
MyList=[]
Chunk_Size = 10000
for chunk in pd.read_csv('Loan_Portfolio_Example_Large.csv', chunksize=Chunk_Size):
    MyList.append(chunk)
```

However, when I use Loan_Portfolio_Example_Large.csv file to create a larger file, namely, Loan_Portfolio_Example_Larger.csv, the following code produces an error.

Note that all I am doing to create the Larger file is I am copying the 100,000 rows from Loan_Portfolio_Example_Large.csv and pasting them 4 times (i.e., pasting in lower rows in excel and saving as csv) to create a file that consists of 500,000 rows and 2509 columns (this file is about 4.2 GB).

The following code creates a parser error and I am unsure why since the data has only gotten larger, I haven't changed the structure of the csv file in any other way, I should have plenty of memory, and I increased the chunk size which shouldn't cause any issues.

Any thoughts? I wonder if the csv is somehow getting corrupted when it is saved (given it is so large.)

```
MyList=[]
Chunk_Size = 100000
for chunk in pd.read_csv('Loan_Portfolio_Example_Larger.csv', chunksize=Chunk_Size):
    MyList.append(chunk)
```

Error output:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 2 MyList=[]
> 3 Chunk_Size = 100000
> ----> 4 for chunk in pd.read_csv('Loan_Portfolio_Example_Larger.csv', chunksize=Chunk_Size):
> 5     MyList.append(chunk)
> 6 print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
> **next**(self)    1126     def **next**(self):    1127         try:
> -> 1128             return self.get_chunk()    1129         except StopIteration:    1130             self.close()
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
> get_chunk(self, size)    1186                 raise StopIteration
> 1187             size = min(size, self.nrows - self._currow)
> -> 1188         return self.read(nrows=size)    1189     1190
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
> read(self, nrows)    1152     def read(self, nrows=None):    1153
> nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
> -> 1154         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)    1155     1156         # May alter columns / col_dict
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
> read(self, nrows)    2057     def read(self, nrows=None):    2058
> try:
> -> 2059             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    2060         except StopIteration:    2061             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
>
> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2509 fields in
> line 145134, saw 3802

Comment: Focus on the last line in the error: Expected 2509 fields in line 145134, saw 3802. There was probably a mistake made when merging the CSV data.Did you miss a carriage return ?

Comment: nope - literally just pasted the data from the first file to the lower rows to increase the file size - I am thinking it was somehow corrupted in the saving step....

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the record 145134 has some delimiter characters in the data and is making it look like it has more columns. Try to use **read_csv** with the parameters below so it will let you know about the records with issues but it will not stop the process.

```
pd.read_csv('Loan_Portfolio_Example_Large.csv', 
             chunksize=Chunk_Size, 
             error_bad_lines=False,
             warn_bad_lines=True)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting exercise - I just tried 200,000 rows and it worked....next is 300,000....

Comment: worked for 300k rows using following:
MyList=[]
Chunk_Size = 50000
for chunk in pd.read_csv('Loan_Portfolio_Example_Large_300k.csv', chunksize=Chunk_Size):
    MyList.append(chunk)

Comment: I am concluding that there was something corrupt in the Larger file....thanks for the help!